# ROSWTF Problems

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
hyness-workstation@hynessworkstation-OptiPlex-755:~$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING ROS_HOSTNAME may be incorrect: ROS_HOSTNAME [ROS_IP] cannot be resolved to an IP address

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: connection refused to [http://192.168.1.100:38906/]
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /turtlebot_dashboard_12116_1344524598265:
   * /diagnostics_toplevel_state


Found 4 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_dashboard_12116_1344524598265] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /turtlebot_dashboard_12116_1344524598265

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /turtlebot_dashboard_12116_1344524598265->/rosout (/rosout)
```

WHAT DO THESE ERRORS MEAN? HOW DO I FIX THEM? THANKS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41011/roswtf-problems/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenjaminYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/23350/benjaminyang/) on 2015-07-25**:
Hey, the ROS tutorials say its roswtf is started in the ros::stack. However when I start roswtf, it read  "No package or stack in context" just likes yours. Does it matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this means that your ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME is different from your computer IP.

Please follow the network setup tutorials for TurtleBot.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0